# OOP: Implementing class that represents three-dimensional, geometrical forms

Tags: java, oop

I'm required to implement a class *Geom* that is capable of representing three-dimensional, geometrical forms. The class possesses two data fields:

```
//colour of the form
public String colour;
//coordinates of the form
public double x, y, z;
```

There are two constructors: The first one transfers all the data fields in the list of parameters, the second one is the "default constructor", who allocates the value *black* to the attribute *colour* and places the form at the point of origin.

The following methods need to be implemented:

1. `public void move(double dX, double dY, double dZ)`, changes the coordinates
2. `public double getVolume()`, gives out the volumn of the *Geom*. For an arbitraty form, this is just `0.0`.
3. `public double getArea()`, gives out the surface content.
4. `public double getDistanteTo(Geom other)`, gives the distance between the position of the *Geom* and the *Geom other* in the euclidian metric.
5. `public String toString()`, gives out all data fields of the *Geom* in a *String*.

I have to write a class that works as an Interface, it looks like this:

```
public interface GeomInterface {

  public void move(double dX, double dY, double dZ);

  public double getVolume();

  public double getArea();

  public double getDistanceTo(Geom other);

  public String toString();

}
```

The next step would be to write the Geom-class:

```
public class Geom implements GeomInterface {

public String colour;
public double x, y, z;
```

That's as far as my knowledge goes. How would I start implementing one of those methods now? Does anyone have an example?

Comment: That has less to do with OOP and more with the algorithm which you are taking in your course as of now.

Comment: Well, that's what they called it.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: bcoz the qiuestion based on this concept may already present on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." - what you presened is basically nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to start off with. You'll have to implement the real logic yourself.

**Geom-class**

```
public class Geom implements GeomInterface {
    private double dx;
    private double dy;
    private double dz;
    private String color;

    public Geom() {
        this.dx = 0;
        this.dy = 0;
        this.dz = 0;
        this.color = "Black";
    }

    public Geom(double dx, double dy, double dz, String color) {
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        this.dz = dz;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void move(double dx, double dy, double dz) {
        // Implement logic here

        // Sample
        this.dx = dx;
    }

    @Override
    public double getVolume() {
        double volume = 0;

        // Implement logic here

        // Sample
        volume = this.dx * this.dy * this.dz;

        return volume;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        double area = 0;

        // Implement logic here 

        // Sample
        area = this.dx * this.dy;

        return area;
    }

    @Override
    public double getDistanceTo(Geom other) {
        double distance = 0;

        // Implement logic here

        // Sample
        distance = this.dx - other.dx; 

        return distance;
    }

    public double getDx() {
        return dx;
    }

    public double getDy() {
        return dy;
    }

    public double getDz() {
        return dz;
    }

    public void setDx(double dx) {
        this.dx = dx;
    }

    public void setDy(double dy) {
        this.dy = dy;
    }

    public void setDz(double dz) {
        this.dz = dz;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

**Test-class**

```
public class TestGeom {
    public TestGeom() {
        Geom geom1 = new Geom();
        Geom geom2 = new Geom(1.0, 2.5, 3.1, "White");

        geom1.setDx(5.3);
        geom1.setDy(1.2);
        geom1.setDz(2.0);
        geom1.setColor("Red");

        System.out.println("Geom1 area: " + geom1.getArea());
        System.out.println("Geom2 volume: " + geom2.getVolume());
        System.out.println("Distance from geom1 to geom2: " + geom1.getDistanceTo(geom2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGeom();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, you should probably omit the setters for the coordinates, as the `move`-method is probably intended for that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a question on the first method: You already gave me that I have to set this.dx = dx. Wouldn't the rest of the method just consist of "this.dy = dy" and "this.dz = dz"? I don't think that there is more to do than to change the coordinates here.

Comment: That's for you to determine, or rather how you interpret the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This is for one method other you should do on your own.

```
public class Geom implements GeomInterface {

   public String colour;
   public double x, y, z;

   //define constructors here

   public double getDistanceTo(Geom other){

       // access local x,y,z as it is
       // access passed x,y,z as other.x,other.y,other.z
       // write some function to get distance between two points and 
       //save it in distance.

       return distance;
   }
}
```